# AngularJS - custom favicon directive

Tags: angularjs

I want to be able to set the href dynamically with AngularJS. The below works only if the custom field is the only one assigned. If there are multiple custom fields, the below will not work. I am new to AngularJS. Do you know what else I could do?

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{user.CustomFields[0].File.Url}}">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way to write this is using the **ngHref** directive.

```
<link rel="icon" ng-href="{{user.CustomFields[0].File.Url}}">
```

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in an href attribute will make the link go to the wrong URL if the user clicks it before Angular has a chance to replace the {{hash}} markup with its value. Until Angular replaces the markup the link will be broken and will most likely return a 404 error. The ngHref directive solves this problem.

[ngHref Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)

***Note***: a similar scenario occurs when using `img` tags.  You should use `ngSrc` in that case

Comment: That does make sense, however, I still can't figure out a way to make this work with multiple fields.

Comment: what do you mean by "multiple fields"?  Do you mean multiple indices in the array?  Or are you trying to composite a url based on multiple values presented in the array?

Comment: The second part - trying to capture a URL that is in an array of objects. If only one of the "custom fields" is assigned, it works, but there could be many of these custom fields.

Comment: I think I need to write a filter function and stick it into the controller, so that the below link would look like this - but this is where I get lost:

    <link rel="shortcut icon" ng-href="{{faviconURL}}">

Comment: If you need to evaluate the object to be able to know the what the url is I would recommend just binding to a method.  i.e. `ng-href="{{getFaviconURL()}}"`

Comment: Thank you for the response!